# Google App Engine App get terminated due to memory limit (at 40MB usage)?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

My GAE backend always get terminated at 40MB memory usage and log said it used too much memory. I don't know why since I used B1/B2 which should have 128/256MB.

Here is the details

I create my GAE app with a frontend module and a backend (in python). The frontend gets the user requests and send to backend. Backend is a image processing app involving google cloud storage service. It needs a long time to finish and consumes some memory as expected.  The backend module run for a long time (5-10mins maybe) so I start the function as a background thread like shown in document:

```
t = background_thread.BackgroundThread(target=f, args=["foo", "bar"])
t.start()
```

Everything works fine on my local development server. However, on cloud, every time the thread is about to finish, it gets terminated. Log said:

> 2014-05-12 18:45:11.826 While handling this request, the process that
>   handled this request was found to be using too much memory and was
>   terminated. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the
>   next request to your application. If you see this message frequently,
>   you may have a memory leak in your application.

I searched a lot, people usually get this message with another message saying "reach soft memory limit" but I only got one message. I checked my memory usage report, the process is always get terminated at 40MB! but I used B1 and B2 which should have 128/256MB limit. Btw, I tried both manual and basic scaling with 1-3 instances.

Even very short run also cause this problem. I tried processing 20 images (each one only 5-10kb) should take tens of seconds to finish at maximum, it still gets killed at 40MB. I also found when my backend idel, it already cost 30 MB. I doubt the image processing will cost hundreds of MB. On my local machine, the image processing usually only take seconds to finish...

My guess is:

Since my function runs as a thread and no further requests coming, google thinks the backend is idle and should not consume such large memory. So gae kills it for memory leaking.
Or, google limit the thread to use only 40MB memory.

By the way, I havn't enable my billing. Will it give me some limit like this?

Can anyone help me with this issue? Thank you very much.

[image: Memory usage figure]

Comment: I am not sure I would believe the graph given you are hitting the soft memory limit.  Try using apptrace to profile your memory use https://code.google.com/p/apptrace/  .  Is there any reason why you don't use a task to run this rather than a thread in a module.  Code would be simpler, but this does assume you will finish in 10min, unless you break the process up and chain tasks.

Comment: apptrace only works in dev, but at least you can see what you real memory consumption will be.

Comment: Thank you, Tim. They are very good advicec. I havn't learned how to use Tasks but seems suitable for my work maybe? I will try your advice.

Comment: It seems I indeed exceeded the memory limit. When I run it on B3, it pop up the exceed soft limit error. I am trying to modify my algorithm. I was too believing in the log's data, which appears not always showing accurate number.

Comment: Also, I think I use too many google cloud storage read/write. They may cost large amount of memory. However I don't see any doc or quantitative number say how much they use and how to avoid. I always close files as soon as possible after I opening them and try to use "cache-control:no-cache" for every write.

Answer (score 2):

Had similar problem with backend instances while running long jobs. Clearing context cache solves the problem.
Try clearing context cache:

```
context = ndb.get_context()
context.clear_cache()
```

Check this out: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/cache#incontext